# how to write "then" as IP constraint in Julia

Tags: optimization, julia, glpk, julia-jump, cost-based-optimizer

[image]

Hello fellows, i am learning Julia and integer programing but i am stuck at one point

How to model "then" in julia-jump for integer programing leanring.

Stuck here  here

```
#Define the variables of the model
@variable(mo, x[1:N,1:S], Bin)
@variable(mo, a[1:S]>=0) 
  

#Assignment constraint
@constraint(mo, [i=1:N], sum(x[i,j] for j=1:S) == 1)

#@constraint (mo, PLEASE HELP )
```

Comment: How about: `x[i,j] <= a[j]/s[i]^2`  (not sure what the `s[i]`s are from the question)

Comment: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/manual/constraints/#Complementarity-constraints may be what you are looking for

Comment: The condition `x[i,j] <= a[j]/s[i]^2` above can also be written as `x[i,j] - (1/s[i]^2)*a[j] <= 0` in a more standard form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases like this you usually need to use Big-M constraints
So this will be:

```
a_ij >= s_i^2 - M*(1-x_ij)
```

where `M` is a "big enough" number. This means that if `x_ij == 0` the inequality will always be true (and hence kind of turned-off). On the other hand when `x_ij == 1` the `M`-part will be zeroed and the equation will hold.

In JuMP terms the code will look like this:

```
const M = 10_000
@constraint(mo, [i=1:N, j=1:S], a[i, j] >= s[i]^2 - M*(1 - x[i, j]))
```

However, if `s[i]` is an external parameter rather than model variable you could simply use `x[i,j] <= a[j]/s[i]^2` proposed by @DanGetz. However when `s[i]` is `@variable` you really want to avoid dividing or multiplying variables by each other. So this big M approach is more general across use cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot fo detailed explanation :) it helped.

Comment: in additon: what if  i want to Introduce the variable y[i,j] defined by y[i,j] = a[j]*x[i,j] ... how would i rewrite its objective function  with linear objective and linear constraints.? i am tring to solve an excercies problem for learning.  thanks already fro your support.